# JSON.NET doesn't reconize colon in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a weird error with JSON.Net in Unity3d, after testing and debuging from my project a level generator that reads the file from the resources and write a file to my desktop. The generator reads specific sections of the json file, this works perfectly. After a crash from the unity Editor while serializing and deserializing data and the old data async.

Since the crash Json.Net gives an error while deserializing a section of the file. And it looks like that Json.Net don't recognize colons anymore. I got the following error:

```
JsonSerializationException: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path 'Levels', line 2, position 12.
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (System.Type objectType) (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T] () (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)
JsonHelper+<GetCollection>d__3`1[T].MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Utils/JsonHelper.cs:25)
```

```
{
   "Levels":[

   ],
   "DefaultConfig":{
      "FieldSize":{
         "Height":25,
         "Width":27
      },
      "FieldBlocks":{
         "BlockScale":3,
         "CenterTop":10,
         "FieldTop":9
      }
   }
}
```

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    private static JObject jsonRoot;

    public static void InitializeJsonHelper(string json)
    {
        jsonRoot = JObject.Parse(json);
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetObjectFromJson<T>(string section)
    {
        JToken token = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
        return token.ToObject<T>();
    }

    public static async Task<List<T>> GetCollection<T>(string section)
    {
        JToken token = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
        return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
    }

    public static async Task<string> AddCollectionToSection<T>(ICollection<T> objects, string section)
    {
        try
        {
            JProperty currentProperty = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
            JProperty newProperty = new JProperty(currentProperty);

            /*var objectsAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);

            newProperty.Value = JToken.Parse(objectsAsJson);*/
            currentProperty.Replace(newProperty);

            await SetReplaceTokenToSection(currentProperty, section);
            return jsonRoot.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.StackTrace;
        }
    }
    public static async Task<string>AddObjectToSection<T>(T newObject, string section)
    {
        JToken token = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
        JValue valueOfToken = new JValue(newObject);
        token.Replace(valueOfToken);

        await SetReplaceTokenToSection(token, section);
        return jsonRoot.ToString();
    }

    private static async Task<JProperty> FindTokenWithSectionName(string section)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             JProperty property = jsonRoot.Property(section);
             return property;
         });
    }

    private static Task SetReplaceTokenToSection(JToken newToken, string section)
    {
        JProperty property = jsonRoot.Property(section);
        property.Value = newToken;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

How can the error be resolved?

Comment: I think 'DefaultConfig' needs to be an array of objects, since you have two in there.

Comment: I think its because `Levels` in your JSON is empty and on multiple lines. If `Levels` is supposed to be empty, it should look like `Levels: []`. Technically what you have is valid JSON, but Unity support for JSON is a bit picky.

Comment: @JabberWocky DefaultConfig must be an object, it has two separate objects inside. Before the crash it works on this way.

Comment: @Ron Beyer it could be possible, but if I read the DefaultConfig first instead of the levels. I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to deserialize a [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) to something.  Instead, you need to deserialize its [value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Value.htm):

```
public static async Task<T> GetObjectFromJson<T>(string section)
{
    JProperty token = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
    return token.Value.ToObject<T>(); // What to do if token is null?
}

public static async Task<List<T>> GetCollection<T>(string section)
{
    JProperty token = await FindTokenWithSectionName(section);
    return token.Value.ToObject<List<T>>(); // What to do if token is null?
}
```

A `JProperty` represents a named value in a `JObject`; you want to deserialize the value itself.

Incidentally, I don't see a reason to make `FindTokenWithSectionName()` run asynchronously.  A `JToken` hierarchy is an in-memory representation of some JSON so no I/O will be performed, and [`JObject.Property(string name)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L285) is just a [dictionary lookup](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JPropertyKeyedCollection.cs#L194) and so should be fast.  And if `JsonHelper` were a mockup of something that is slow, such as a database lookup, I wouldn't expect the class to be static, since static classes aren't suited to be used for dependency injection.

Also, using a static field in a static class to capture some runtime-loaded JSON looks to be potentially thread-unsafe.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0aLSET).